# phpseclib - set IV modify images data URI

Tags: php, encryption, phpseclib, data-uri

I'm using phpseclib to encrypt/decrypt data uri of some images. I've noticed that when I'm using the IV the `data:image/png;base64`,`data:image/jpg;base64`,`data:image/jpeg;base64` part of the passed data uri will be lost, only the rest of the base64 string will remain and I will be unable to display the images after decryption operations. Is possible to use the IV without loosing the that part of each data uri encrypted?

```
//data URI creation from uploaded image using PHP-dataURI https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-dataURI
$dataObject = DataURI\Data::buildFromFile('myimage.jpg');
//data URI encrypt
$cipher = new AES();
//set password for encryption
$cipher->setPassword($password);
//set the IV - this will corrupt data uri generated
$cipher->setIV(Random::string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));
//encrypting the data
$output = $cipher->encrypt(DataURI\Dumper::dump($dataObject));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44972783/1816580 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/44694994/1816580

Comment: @ArtjomB. The implementations of the questions you've suggested are for c# and java. I'm using PHP so I can't find any useful info that can help me to solve the issue. Anyway thanks.

Comment: You're saying that your decryption returns mangled plaintext. Let me rephrase the linked answers for you. The IV needs to be the same during decryption as encryption for that single ciphertext. If you create a random IV without saving it then you will not be able to recover the first 16 bytes of the plaintext during decryption. The IV is not secret, but can be sent along with the ciphertext. We usually prepend it to the ciphertext. Does this help?

Comment: ok, butI'm using the library function to attach the IV `$cipher->setIV(Random::string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3));` I'm not sure that I can do the same and achive the same result on decrypt, I've done it as proposed from the documentation

Comment: You can: `$iv = Random::string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3); $cipher->setIV($iv);` and then you can use `$iv` during decryption. If you have to send it or store it then this is a different question.

Comment: I've solved the problem by prepending the `$iv` to the encrypted data, I will post the code as soon as I can. Thanks for the help

Comment: Don't forget to include the complete code including the decryption part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I've used to solve this issue. I'm new to phplibsec so I was using `$cipher->setIV(Random::string($cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3))` method in a wrong way to set and read the IV. The phpseclib documentations are not very useful and lack of examples on how to implement correctly encrypt and decrypt methods, in particular no example of how to manage the IV is provided. After some research here on SO and thanks to the help of community, I've figured out how to manage the IV.

Encryption of the data uri:

```
//data URI creation from uploaded image using PHP-dataURI https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-dataURI
$dataObject = DataURI\Data::buildFromFile('myimage.jpg');
//data URI encrypt
$cipher = new AES();
//set password for encryption
$cipher->setPassword($password);
//random IV creation
$iv = Random::string($cipher->getBlockSize() >> 3);
//set the IV
$cipher->setIV($iv);
//encrypting the data
$encrypted = $cipher->encrypt(DataURI\Dumper::dump($dataObject));
//output
$output = $iv.$encrypted;
```

Into the encryption script I've assigned the random generated IV to a variable that after encryption is prepended to the encrypted data. This because the IV is needed to decrypt correctly the data and this imply that it need to be stored in a database or appended/prepended to the data (no, there is no security risk by doing this). The prepended IV then can be extracted from the encrypted data using the `substr()` function in this way:

```
//data URI decrypt
$cipher = new AES();
//set previously selected password for encryption
$cipher->setPassword($password);
//extract the IV from encrypted data
$ivLength = $cipher->getBlockLength() >> 3;
$iv = substr($encrypted, 0, $ivLength);
//set the IV
$cipher->setIV($iv);
//removing the IV from the data before decrypt
$data = substr($encrypted, $ivLength);
//decrypting the data
$output = $cipher->decrypt($data);
```

After the decrypt the original base64 data uri will be returned back as expected.